# Vueify / Browserify throwing ENOENT at standard configuration

Tags: node.js, browserify, vue.js

### My problem:

I tried to follow the steps from: https://github.com/vuejs/vueify

But when I try to run this command:

```
browserify -t vueify -e src/main.js -o build/build.js
```

I receive this error message:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: ENOENT, open 'c:\Users\Justin\phonegap-projects\cc\build\build.js'
```

---

### My question:

How can I organize my project to work comfortable with VueJS and Vueify? Or what should I do to complete the steps in the given link?

---

### Notes:

- I ran this command from my directory structure (and tried from the node_modules too, but that didn't felt right to me)
- Before I did this, I installed VueJS itself (also with npm)

My directory structure:

```
- hooks (part of Phonegap)
- node_modules
- platforms (part of Phonegap)
- plugins (part of Phonegap)
- www (Phonegap directory with the HTML/CSS/JS)
    - index.html
    - css
    - img
    - js (I guess I need the compiled file here)
    - res
    - spec
    - views
    - index.html
    - spec.html
- [file] config.xml
```

Just to mention, the node modules I received now (just in case I missed something):

```
- babel-plugin-transform-runtime
- babel-preset-es2015
- babel-runtime
- uniq
- vue
- vue-hot-reload-api
- vueify
- vueify-insert-css
```

Comment: I don't see your `src/main.js` and `build/build.js` files in the file structure you posted. I was working with Vue and gulp-watch, and I've got similar errors, the point is that error handling isn't that good in those tasks, in my case, I was attempting to write a file that already exist, what your problem is saying is that your file is already open, i guess. What I did was to use `fs` module to check if the file exists, but that isn't posible here because you are just using a command

Comment: I would suggest you to try to use your tools with gulp. Checkout [this](https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/110) github issue for a simple code snippet, hope it helps

Comment: I have edited the title. This is a problem with node, but more specifically the vueify documentation. Also I did just copy-pasted the command and was mislead, but this just OS stuff. See answer below.

Comment: Where is your `src` directory?

Answer (score 0):

In this case `node` is likely just complaining, that there is no `build/` folder. The rest should be fine.